# Some email clients unable to decrypt email sent from Outlook 2010

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

mimekit  unable to decrypt email sent from Outlook 2010 ,the error is has no private key,but mimekit   decrypt email sent from Outlook 2013 is well, Online data display is the bug for  Outlook 2010 , but iphone can  decrypt email sent from Outlook 2010

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have not imported your private key into your `SecureMimeContext`.

Without a private key, you can't decrypt the message (otherwise if a private key wasn't needed, what would be the point of encryption?)

Comment: I apologize for my own English,
    Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013 using the same certificate (including the private key)
 to send a mail,when the client received the mail , Outlook 
2013 can be decrypted, Outlook 2010 unable to decrypt , The official explanation is 
Outlook 2010 Defects, the link is
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2142236/some-email-clients-unable-to-decrypt-email-sent-from-outlook-2010)
 but this message iphone mail client can decrypt,if i want to decrypt  the mail from
 Outlook 2010,what should I do？
Hopes your help! thanks!